# Change many values from with one in a column

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(mynumber = c(1,2,3), trend = c(4,3,1))
```

How can find in trend  column which rows contain the number 4 or 1 and change with the text google?

I tried this one

```
df[which(df$trend == "4|1")] <- "google"
```

Comment: It would be `%in%` `df$trend[df$trend %in% c(4, 1)] <- "google"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```r
df <- data.frame(mynumber = c(1,2,3), trend = c(4,3,1))
df[which(df$trend == 4 | df$trend == 1),1] <- "google"
df
>  df
>  mynumber trend
> 1   google     4
> 2        2     3
> 3   google     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `tidyverse` library using the [`mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) function.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(mynumber = c(1,2,3), trend = c(4,3,1))
new_df <-  df %>% mutate(mynumber = if_else(trend ==4 | trend == 1, 'google', as.character(mynumber)))
new_df
#>   mynumber trend
#> 1   google     4
#> 2        2     3
#> 3   google     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>